# Where can I find boundaries of all German voting districts in federal elections (since 1949)?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, germany

Where can I find shapefiles containing the boundaries of all voting districts in German federal elections, 1949-2021?

Comment: If you're looking for data, OpenData.SE is a better place to ask. Also, have you tried official sources?

Comment: Will try OpenData.SE. Official sources only provide shapefiles for current voting districts.